# Impossible to include OpenCV path in Qt Creator

Tags: opencv, qmake, include-path

I am trying to configure a new Qt Creator project in order to use OpenCV 3.1.0 in Windows 10. I downloaded the precompiled binaries from http://opencv.org/downloads.html, and I created an empty Qt gui project. The problem is that qmake doesn't find the opencv headers, no matter how I try to include their path. Here is my last attempt:

```
QT       += core gui
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = App_v1
TEMPLATE = app

INCLUDEPATH += C:/OpenCV-3.1.0/opencv/build/include
LIBS += -L”C:\OpenCV-3.1.0\opencv\build\x64\vc14\lib”
LIBS += -lopencv_world310d

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp
HEADERS  += mainwindow.h
FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

And the source:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cv::Mat image = cv::Mat::zeros(100, 100, CV_8UC3);
    cv::imshow("image", image);
    cv::waitKey(10);

    cout << "Hello cout!" << endl;
    cerr << "Hello cerr!" << endl;
    printf("Hello printf!");
    cout << flush;

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

When I try to compile this, I get: "C1083: Cannot open include file: 'opencv2/core/core.hpp": No such file or directory
(btw thanks Qt Creator for not letting me select and copy the text of the error. Sorry I digress...)

I am sure that the path is correct, and the funny thing is that when I type cv:: the auto completion finds and lists the classes and functions in the cv namespace.... what is going on here?

And btw, OpenCV works perfectly with Visual Studio, so I know that It is installed correctly...

Comment: Shouldn't it be `C:\OpenCV-3.1.0\opencv\build\x64\vc14\lib` instead of `C:\OpenCV-3.1.0\opencv\build\x64\vc14\bin` ?

Comment: @Sunreef  Yes indeed. That was my second mistake, and it caused a linking error (corrected now). In this case, core.hpp could not be loaded not because of an incorrect setting in the .pro file, but because the project needed a cleaning...

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the problem was that the project needed a cleaning... I did not think about it, since I am used to visual studio. I believe that the cleaning step should be performed automatically before each rebuild, since it does not make sense that some leftovers from previous builds make the current build fail...